# julia - Function doesnt accept a tuple including a function as parameter

Tags: julia

I'm having some issue with julia's typing system.  Can someone please clarify?

```
ValidationRule = Tuple{DataType,Symbol}
ValidationRuleWithConversion = Tuple{DataType,Symbol,<:Function}

function validate(rules::Vector{Union{ValidationRule,ValidationRuleWithConversion}})

end

validate([
    (String, :name, convert_name),
    (String, :age)
])
```

And more generally this should work somehow:

```
function myfunc(arg::Tuple{Vararg}) end

myfunc((:name, a -> a.value))
```

Answer (score 2):

The element type of an array constructed with `[a, b, ...]` is essentially `typejoin(typeof(a), typeof(b), ...)` (ignoring promotion rules), which in this case means the element type is `Tuple{DataType, Symbol, Vararg{typeof(convert_name)}}`. This type is not the same as your union type since `Vararg` here means any number of `typeof(convert_name)`.

You can force the array to have the correct type to make this work:

```
EitherValidationRule = Union{ValidationRule, ValidationRuleWithConversion}

validate(EitherValidationRule[
    (String, :name, convert_name),
    (String, :age)
])
```

But it seems like it would be better to make a proper struct for each type of validation rule and subtype AbstractValidationRule, for instance.

Comment: There has to be a way to accept the type.  Updated question.

Comment: Well `Vector{Tuple{DataType, Symbol, Vararg{typeof(convert_name)}}}` would accept the array type in your first example, but I wouldn't do this. I'm not sure what the update means - should the same function accept a single tuple? If you don't want to package the data in structs and instead want a more flexible API I would just not specify argument types at all, i.e. a more pythonic style